# MySQL parenthesis performance impact?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sqlperformance

Say I had a MySQL query like this:

```
SELECT id,
       something,
       CASE colour
           WHEN 1 THEN 'not ripe' 
           WHEN 2 THEN 'ripe'
           ELSE 'rotten'
       END AS 'ripeness' 
FROM fruit 
WHERE fruit_type = 'apple'
```

If I wrapped the `CASE` in parenthesis because I find it more readable:

```
SELECT id,
       something,
       (CASE colour
           WHEN 1 THEN 'not ripe' 
           WHEN 2 THEN 'ripe'
           ELSE 'rotten'
       END) AS 'ripeness' 
FROM fruit 
WHERE fruit_type = 'apple'
```

Would that have a performance impact on the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both these queries are semantically equivalent. There shouldn't be any noticeable performance impact on using or not using parenthesis.

Comment: Cool thank you. is there a best practice to use or not to use parenthesis there?

Comment: @JohnnyFaldo It's a matter of taste, really. Personally, I don't like these parenthesis, but I have colleagues who swear by them.

Comment: depends on your coding style, basically  make code nice and easy to read.

Answer (score 1):

don't think so, only time difference should be the compiler to decode your parenthesis,they will be compiled into same binary.

You can run a big data test to find out.